# How to open a directory contains "-"?

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, directory

How can I open a directory via `PUTTY` that contains `-`?

For example the name of dir is:

```
some-thing-dir
```

`cd /some-thing-dir` not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "cd" into a directory with this name "-2"?](http://serverfault.com/questions/462739/how-to-cd-into-a-directory-with-this-name-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it should be working.... what error message do you get? Nevertheless you can try to escape the dash:

```
cd /some\-thing\-dir
```

Comment: for `/home$ cd /movie\-economics\-lawyer\-science` I get

`-bash: cd: /movie-economics-lawyer-science: No such file or directory`

Comment: ls -ld /movie-economics-lawyer-science, please

Comment: The directory is inside your home directory? then you should not use the first slash because that means it is an absolute path. you can use "cd /home/movie/some-dir" or: "cd /home/movie; cd some-dir"

Comment: ls -ld gives `drwxr-x--- 10 movie-economics-lawyer-science movie-economics-lawyer-science 4096 May 14 10:49 /home/movie-economics-lawyer-science`

Comment: cd /home/movie-economics-lawyer-science

Comment: And `"cd /home/movie/some-dir` gives me : Permission denied :o

Comment: so then the user that created the directory was not you and it does not have the +x flag for all users set - try to access it as "root" or set the correct permissions

Answer (score 1):

You should try e.g. `cd ./home\-movie\-economics` or perhaps `cd 'home-movie-economics'`

Comment: what's the point in escaping the dashes in the first example and not escaping them in the second one? ;)

Comment: @PascalSchmiel, the apostrophes quote.

Comment: ahh, don't get it, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Just quote it.

```
cd /'some-thing-dir'
```